# How can I move a tub drain plunger, if the linkage chain is missing?

Tags: bathtub, drain

The broken linkage chain was removed from our tub a couple of years ago. All has been good until now the plunger has fallen shut and the water drains v e r y, v e r y  s l o w l y. any suggestions how to get it unstuck? I don't even need it to be there are all, so if it can be remove that is just as well.

Comment: You could try fishing the plunger out with a coat hanger, or a scrap piece of solid core electrical wire.

Comment: Thank you, I did try try that. Didn't seem flexible enough.

Comment: Fish tape may be able to be flexible enough but if you just want to remove it you'll need access to the pipes below the tub to determine if you just have to replace the fittings or you need to cut out pieces and replace.

Comment: Check this out: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8783/how-do-i-retrieve-a-detached-plunger-from-a-bathtub-drain

Answer (score 1):

Typically these aren't chains at all, but a rod in two pieces. See link provided by Getterdun. If you can grab that lower piece, you can pull it up and completely remove the stopper, by removing the overflow cover.

I've done this on several tubs over the years, and simply used a rubber stopper in the tub when needed. Newer tubs typically don't use this lever and rod, but have a decorative stopper at the drain itself, harking back to the old rubber stopper on a chain idea, but, of course, costing more, and looking somewhat nicer.