# Trip lever tub drainage broken inside tub - is there a way to get it out?

Tags: drain, bathtub

I pushed the trip lever down after a bath and the linkage broke so now the tub won’t drain. I removed the lever and linkage, but the plunger is still down there. I found a tip about using a c-hook to grasp the plunger, but the loop on top the plunger broke off with the linkage. Is there anything I can do to get the plunger out myself? This is an upstairs bathroom if that makes a difference.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Presumably the standard modern tub installation with no access panel, so you'll have to cut through a wall or floor to get at the drain from outside? Hint - if you have to do that, cut the hole the size of an access panel you buy, and install that when your are done.

Comment: The canonical question is here, https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/8783/18078 but with the connection on the plunger broken off you're going to have to hope you can budge it (and presumably it's somewhat stuck or it wouldn't have broken) by hooking the bottom edge of the "bucket" stopper, which seems less than likely to work.